# Edit a css file from the live website

Tags: php, html, css, dreamweaver

so i want to develop a mini website builder within my website. Have a control panel where users can edit the text in their websites, i want each of those html pages to have its own css file attached to it. Now, i want it so that the user sees something like a button saying "Edit Background color" they are prompted with a color picker and on hitting save, the css file is updated without them knowing that css even exists.

I would like to know what language i can use to make the previous example happen. And if possible a hint of code.

I appreciate your answers, Braulio :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't downvote you but just for informational purposes, the reason you were probably downvoted is due to the scope of your question,  The language you choose depends on what platform you are running your site on.  And it is likely possible to do what you want in tons of different languages assuming your platform supports them.  For an easy solution check out .net languages like c# with ajax controls for live updates without refreshes.    But then again you could use ruby with rails.    Or you could do most of it in the client side with jquery and javascript then send the results to the server which could utilize php.  It is just to broad a question to really answer without writing the whole thing for you which nobody is going to do.